# WSOD on Drupal page admin/content and context module edit

Tags: php, drupal, wsod

I am having trouble figuring out why I am getting a white screen of death on the pages admin/content and admin/structure/context/list/main_menu/edit (Context module edit page).

I upgraded a Drupal 6 site to 7 using drush and then the problem occurred.

I have tried everything mentioned in forums, on here, and all over google. Increasing my memory_limit and max_execution_time has not solved the problem.

Please enlighten me.

Comment: This is kind of a silly question isn't it? You already tried everything? 
To get people to help you should at least be more specific. What about error messages? What are the logs saying? Drupal reports?

Comment: There is nothing in the logs. No error message. No Drupal reports. Also error_reporting is turned on and display_logs is on. Other errors are logged correctly

Comment: Ok, try to detach the drupal error handler in `includes/bootstrap.inc` on ~ line 2288 (`set_error_handler('_drupal_error_handler');`) and see if there are any messages now. And if you're able to debug the hole thing start in `modules/node/node.admin.inc` on line 405 where the form is build that shows your content.